# Reference book for smooth manifolds

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds

I want a book to cover the following topics in smooth manifolds:

$1.$smooth structures, smooth maps, Bump functions
$2.$ Partitions of Unity, Extension Lemma, Tangent Vectors, Pushforwards
$3.$ Tangent Bundles, Vector fields, Vector Bundles, Bundle Maps, Sections,
Cotangent Bundles
$4.$ Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem, Submanifolds, Submersions, Level
sets, Statement of Sard’s Theorem
$5.$ Differential Forms, Wedge product, Exterior Derivative, Definition only of
De Rham     Cohomology groups
$6.$ Orientation, Riemannian Volume form
$7.$ Integration on Manifolds using differential forms, Stoke's Theorem

I want a book that covers these topics. It is not that a single book should contain all of these but it would be better if it is so. The book should be interesting, have some good problems to work on (would be better if it is provided with hints to hard problems).

Comments and suggestions are needed.

Comment: [An Introduction to Manifolds By Loring W. Tu](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Manifolds/xQsTJJGsgs4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) and [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds
By John Lee](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds/xygVcKGPsNwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) and [An Introduction to Differential Manifolds
By Jacques Lafontaine](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Differential_Manifold/KNhJCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: thanks u @Mathlover

Comment: Also, [An Introduction To Differential Manifolds
By Dennis Barden, Charles B Thomas](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_To_Differential_Manifold/8M02DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=differential+manifold+imperial+college+press&pg=PR4&printsec=frontcover) and [Differentiable Manifolds
By Lawrence Conlon](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Differentiable_Manifolds/tzPTBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Differentiable+ManifoldsSecond+EditionLawrence+Conlon&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover) and [Freely available nice book](https://folk.uib.no/nmabd/dt/dtcurrent.pdf)

Comment: [An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry
By William M. Boothby](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Differentiable_Manifo/U19EgdcSQckC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) and [Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups
By Frank W. Warner](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Foundations_of_Differentiable_Manifolds/S_7lBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Frank+W.+WarnerFOUNDATIONSof+DIFFERENTIABLE+MANIFOLDSand+LIE+GROUPS&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: [Differential Topology
By Amiya Mukherjee](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Differential_Topology/aD8PCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=differential+topology+amiya+mukherjee+pdf&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @Mathlover I don't think you suggested enough references.